# Https redirect from DNS Host?

Tags: redirect, heroku, dns

So I'm trying to figure out if this is something I can configure through my DNS host or if I need to set this up on my app server.

**My situation**

I have a heroku app and domain name (lets say example.com) which is set up for https on both *www* and *root/apex*. So https://example.com and https://www.example.com **both work**. I am also able to redirect any http requests (both www or root/apex) to domain to the https equivalent so in other words:

http://www. redirects to https://www.  and http://root redirect to https://root.

**My issue**

I want all combinations of my urls (http or https and www or root) to direct to a single url (https://www or https://root). My aim is to just have consistency in the urls. I noticed that most redirects work EXCEPT when trying to redirect from https://example.com to anything else.

What is the DNS host approach for this? And if it's not possible from DNS host the normal approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS provides translation from the domain name in a URL to an IP address that the client can contact. If your problem involves *anything else whatsoever* in the URL, it's not a problem DNS can solve.

The problem you describe involves the difference between HTTP and HTTPS. This is not part of the domain name in the URL. Therefore, DNS is not your problem.